# TypeError when ordering table data in Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xpath, typeerror

I'm trying to read table data from Yahoo Finance with Python 2.7 and have it give me a 2-dimensional list of all the data. Here's my code so far:

```
def getStocks():
    from lxml import html
    import requests

    page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=INTC+Options")
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

    output = [["Strike"]["Contract Name"]["Last"]["Bid"]["Ask"]["Change"]["\% Change"]["Volume"]["Open Interest"]["Implied Volatility"]]
    for x in range(10):
        colData = tree.xpath('//tr[@data-row-quote="_"]/td[{}]//*[text()]/text()'.format(x + 1))
        output[x].extend(colData)
```

Now when I run this, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Python\stock_get.py", line 17, in <module>
    getStocks()
  File "C:\Users\username\Python\stock_get.py", line 8, in getStocks
    output = [["Strike"]["Contract Name"]["Last"]["Bid"]["Ask"]["Change"]["\% Change"]["Volume"]["Open Interest"]["Implied Volatility"]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I've looked through other answers, but I'm not sure what they mean.

Is there a better way to return all the table data in a legible way with headers of some sort?

If not, how can I solve this error? I want it to give me something like this:

```
[["Strike", "28.00", "30.00", "30.50"...], ["Contract Name", "INTC150206C00028000"...], and_so_on]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining a list of lists here:

```
output = [["Strike"]["Contract Name"]["Last"]["Bid"]["Ask"]["Change"]["\% Change"]["Volume"]["Open Interest"]["Implied Volatility"]]
```

You are trying to **index** the first list with `["Strike"][...]`, so Python sees that the first part is a list and expects the second part to pass in an integer, but finds a string instead.

You appear to have forgotten to add commas:

```
output = [["Strike"], ["Contract Name"], ["Last"], ["Bid"], ["Ask"],
          ["Change"], ["\% Change"], ["Volume"], ["Open Interest"], 
          ["Implied Volatility"]]
```